# Kafka KStream - topology design

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My stream is key/value pairs that I want to save to a db as 'raw' and by 60 second aggregation. Originally I was doing this:

```
                       ->foreach
                     /
kStreamBuilder.stream->aggregateBy->process
```

but then I found out that

a. `.aggregateby()` only returns the pairs that it matches (I need all of them - matched or otherwise)
b. I could achieve the same aggregation effect using a **HashMap** in the `.process()` phase. Then when `.punctuate()` is called I write all k/v pairs to the db.

So the resultant topology becomes:

`kStreamBuilder.stream->foreach`
`kStreamBuilder.stream->process`

### Questions:

1. Is this a 'reasonable' way to attain the result of writing all kv pairs matched or otherwise? (all values via **foreach** and any pairs + the rest via **process**)
2. Do I need to (somehow) divide the original stream before sending it to `.foreach()` and `.process()` or is it sufficient to do the above?

Comment: Which `aggregateBy` method are you referring to?  There's no such method in Kafka 0.10.0.  And what do you mean by "matches"?  What you are doing above is aggregating a single stream -- I don't follow what you are matching against.  Lastly, in general I would recommend to not use `foreach()` to forward data from Kafka (and a Kafka Streams app);  use Kafka Connect instead.  One reason is: Kafka and Kafka Streams will soon have exactly-once semantics, but you'll lose *end-to-end* exactly-once semantics for a Kafka->DB pipeline if you use `foreach()` (b/c this method is a blackbox for Streams).

Comment: My mistake - it should have referred to [.aggregateByKey](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#aggregateByKey(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Initializer,%20org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Aggregator,%20org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windows))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregation in DSL layer is designed for "incremental aggregation", ie, current aggregation result plus single new value to be "added". If you want to access all "raw record" of a 60-second window at once, you need to use Processor API.

And you do not need to do anything if you have two downstream operators. Records will be forwarded to both automatically. However, keep in mind, they are not replicated, ie, both downstream operator will see the same Java object for each record!

Comment: That's the result I want. The `.forEach` will record every individual record and the `.process` will pair up anything that occurs more than once + write everything to aggregated store.